# Diffeomorphisms preserve tangency between curves

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, parametrization

I've been trying to solve the following problem:

Prove that if two regular curves $C_1$ and $C_2$ of a regular surface $S$ are tangent at a point $p \in S$, and if $\alpha\colon S \to S$ is a diffeomorphism, then $\alpha(C_1)$ and $\alpha(C_2)$ are regular curves which are tangent at $\alpha(p)$.

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you define a regular surface?

Comment: If there exists a parametrization from an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ to a neighborhood of any point in the surface $S$

Comment: It seems to me that $a$ should be isometry for it to hold. Check related posts on MSE.

Comment: Thanks @Test123. I will

Comment: I did not find anything related to this problem